# Neat way to get descriptor object

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor, python-descriptors

In Python 3

```
class A(object):
    attr = SomeDescriptor()
    ...
    def somewhere(self):
        # need to check is type of self.attr is SomeDescriptor()
        desc = self.__class__.__dict__[attr_name]
        return isinstance(desc, SomeDescriptor)
```

Is there better way to do it? I don't like this `self.__class__.__dict__` stuff

Comment: How about `type(self).__dict__['attr']` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`A.attr` causes Python to call `SomeDescriptor().__get__(None, A)` so if you have `SomeDescriptor.__get__` return `self` when `inst` is `None`, then `A.attr` will return the descriptor:

```
class SomeDescriptor():
    def __get__(self, inst, instcls):
        if inst is None:
            # instance attribute accessed on class, return self
            return self
```

Then you access the descriptor with

```
desc  = type(self).attr
```

If the attribute's name is known only as a string, `attr_name`, then you would use

```
desc  = getattr(type(self), attr_name)
```

This works even if `self` is a instance of a **subclass** of `A`, whereas

```
desc = self.__class__.__dict__[attr_name]
```

would only work if `self` is an instance of `A`.

---

```
class SomeDescriptor():
    def __get__(self, inst, instcls):
        if inst is None:
            # instance attribute accessed on class, return self
            return self
        return 4

class A():
    attr = SomeDescriptor()
    def somewhere(self):
        attr_name = 'attr'
        desc  = getattr(type(self), attr_name)
        # desc = self.__class__.__dict__[attr_name]  # b.somewhere() would raise KeyError
        return isinstance(desc, SomeDescriptor)
```

This shows `A.attr` returns the descriptor, and `a.somewhere()` works as expected:

```
a = A()
print(A.attr)
# <__main__.SomeDescriptor object at 0xb7395fcc>    
print(a.attr)
# 4    
print(a.somewhere())
# True
```

This shows it works for subclasses of `A` too. If you uncomment
`desc = self.__class__.__dict__[attr_name]`, you'll see 
`b.somewhere()` raises a KeyError:

```
class B(A): pass
b = B()
print(B.attr)
# <__main__.SomeDescriptor object at 0xb7395fcc>   
print(b.attr)
# 4    
print(b.somewhere())
# True
```

---

By the way, even if you do not have full control over the definition of SomeDescriptor, you can still wrap it in a descriptor which returns `self` when `inst` is None:

```
def wrapper(Desc):
    class Wrapper(Desc):
        def __get__(self, inst, instcls):
            if inst is None: return self
            return super().__get__(inst, instcls)
    return Wrapper

class A():
    attr = wrapper(SomeDescriptor)()
    def somewhere(self):
        desc  = type(self).attr
        # desc = self.__class__.__dict__[attr_name]  # b.somewhere() would raise KeyError
        return isinstance(desc, SomeDescriptor)
```

So there is no need to use

```
desc = self.__class__.__dict__[attr_name]
```

or

```
desc = vars(type(self))['attr']
```

which suffers from the same problem.

Comment: This will get instance attributes, if they're different from the class' attributes, right? Otherwise I prefer `getattr` over other approaches.

Comment: Please elaborate. I do not understand what situation you are contemplating.

Comment: `a = A(); a.attr = = 5; getattr(type(a), 'attr', None)`. Won't that be `5` and not `4`?

Comment: @2rs2ts: No it would not. It still returns the descriptor. Try it! :)

Comment: Oh, I'd have to do `getattr(a, 'attr', None)` for what I'm talking about, yeah?

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yes. `getattr(a, 'attr')` suffices, since `None` is the default. Moreover, `a.attr` would still access the descriptor ahead of the instance `__dict__` if the descriptor is a data descriptor (i.e. also defines `__set__`). See [Python attributes and methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#two-kinds-of-descriptors).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, to access descriptors on a class, the only way to prevent [`descriptor.__get__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) from being invoked is to go through the class `__dict__`.

You could use [`type(self)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to access the current class, and [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to access the `__dict__` in more API-compliant ways:

```
desc = vars(type(self))['attr']
```

If your descriptor is entirely custom, you can always return `self` from `SomeDescriptor.__get__()` if the *instance* argument is `None`, which happens when you access the descriptor directly on the class. You can drop the `vars()` call and go straight to:

```
desc = type(self).attr
```

The `property()` descriptor object does exactly this.