# How can I access attributes stored on Python descriptors?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following descriptor:

```
class MyDescriptor(object):

    def __init__(self, name, type_):
        self.name = name
        self.type_ = type_

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        assert isinstance(value, self.type_)
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

Is there a way to access `type_` from an object employing `MyDescriptor`?

i.e.

```
class MyObject(object):
    x = MyDescriptor('x', int)

my_object = MyObject()
my_object.x = 5
print my_object.x.type_
```

As far as I'm aware, this will raise `AttributeError` as `my_object.x` is an `int`. But, I'm wondering if there's a good way to associate metadata with descriptors.

EDIT: adjusted wording to indicate that there's one instance of a descriptor per class.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to name the field `type_` with the underscore. For the parameter it makes sense but `self.type` doesn't shadow anything so it's fine.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629397/neat-way-to-get-descriptor-object

Comment: @alex hall Good point! But, while that's true, it results in code like `self.__class__.x.type_` or `my_object.__class__.x.type` in practice. Which, I suppose isn't terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to access type_ from the object instance which owns the MyDescriptor instance?

There is no object instance which owns the MyDescriptor instance.  There is *one* instance of MyDescriptor which is stored on the *class* of which the descriptor is an attribute (`MyObject` in your example).  That's how descriptors work.  You can access this descriptor instance via the class as described in user2357112's answer, but be aware that you're accessing class-level data.  If you want to store instance-level data with the descriptor, you need to store it on the instance itself (i.e., on the object passed as `obj` to your `__set__`/`__get__`) rather than on the descriptor.

Comment: Marking this as the solution since it revealed the incorrect assumption in my question and led to some helpful edits and a better course of action in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the actual descriptor object. For your descriptor, that can be done with

```
type(my_object).x.type_
```

or

```
MyObject.x.type_
```

For descriptors where `MyObject.x` is not the actual descriptor object, such as functions on Python 2, you may need to find the descriptor by looking in the class `__dict__`, or looking through the dicts of all classes in the MRO if you want a generic way to find inherited descriptors. (For the specific case I just mentioned, you can also use the `__func__` attribute of the unbound method object, but that won't work for other descriptors.)

Comment: This is true, but the question indicates that the OP thinks there is a separate descriptor object for each instance of MyObject.  There is not.  So you can do this, but, as described in my answer, it may not do what the OP hopes.